# ¿Por qué el UPDATE con la línea del WHERE en mysql no realiza las actualizaciones en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

```
    <html lang="es">
       <body class="body">
            <form action="editar.php" method="post" class="form_contact">
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $datos['nombre_apellido'];?>" class="name entry " name="nombre_apellido" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required/>
                <input type="email" value="<?php echo $datos['email'];?>" class="email entry" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"/>
                <textarea class="message entry" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje"><?php echo $datos['mensaje'];?></textarea>
                <button class="submit" name="guardar">Guardar</button>
            </form>
            
            <?php
            break;
            }
            }
      
            if(isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
    
            $nombre_apellido = $_POST['nombre_apellido'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    
            mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE contactos SET
            nombre_apellido = '$nombre_apellido',
            email = '$email',
            mensaje = '$mensaje',
            WHERE mensaje = '$mensaje'"); #El where de un update debe ir sobre una llave primaria
    
            header('Location: solicitudes_contacto.php');
            exit();
            }
    
            include("cerrar_conexion.php");
            ?>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Por que UPDATE con WHERE en mysql no realiza cambios en mi base de datos. Aclaro que mensaje es una clave primaria. Si quito la línea de código del WHERE sí actualiza pero me modifica todas las filas de la base de datos.

Comment: no conozco mucho php, pero `$conexion` donde está declarado, tal vez sea eso

Comment: es esto $conexion = new mysqli($host,$usuariodb,$clavedb,$basededatos);

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la estructura de la tabla? No tiene mucho sentido lo que estás intentando hacer. Si en efecto mensaje es LA clave primaria (solo puede haber una) ¿qué pasa cuando el usuario cambia el mensaje? ¿exactamente qué registro quieres actualizar?

Comment: considera esto. el mensaje del registro original es `hola` y `$mensaje` al momento de guardar tiene `adios`. en tu consulta, le estás diciendo que actualice con `adios` el campo mensaje, a todos los registros ***Cuyo mensaje en base de datos sea `hola`, cosa que así como está el código nunca va a pasar***

Comment: Tal y como dice Rubio acá, estás actualizando un dato, no puedes poner el NUEVO dato como validador. Es como si dijeras, `cambia el numero 2 al numero 3, donde el numero 2 = 3` ... nunca funcionará. Debes usar el ID del mensaje el cual no tienes nisiquiera llamado.

Comment: es solo un código de prueba, la funcionalidad es mala pero yo solo quiero resolver la lógica del código, ya que he colocado a nombre_apellido como clave primaria e email pero no cambia el resultado/retorno. Me gustaría poder comprender por qué no actualiza la base de datos mi código.

Comment: es muy mala práctica el utilizar algo así como llave primaria, por lo general, se crea un campo exclusivo como identificador único, ya sea un dni, un UUID o algo por el estilo. Pero siguiendo tu código como está, tu condición de filtrado debería ser algo que sólo tenga el registro que desees actualizar, que nunca cambie

Comment: Te lo estamos explicando claro bro, no tienes un validador adecuado. DEBES actualizar un dato, conociendo su ID ... no usando otras cosas. DEBES ponerle un ID a la fila de CONTACTOS. Cargar el ID al leer el mensaje, y pasarlo al editar para poder actualizarlo.

Comment: entiendo la buena práctica pero no comprendo porque no actualiza por ejemplo cuando cambio la línea a WHERE email = '$email'"); que es lo que hace que no se modifique

Comment: @Excorpion no tengo permiso para hablar por chat

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125032/gcb

Comment: si vi lo del puntaje @Excorpion pero no me permite responder mensajes, muchas gracias igual

Comment: Ya tienes 51 puntos, deberías poder acceder al chat sin problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El OP tiene varios errores que le sobran,
Se puso en contacto con el por chat para responder todo.

- Falta del uso de ID
- Mala aplicación de claves primarias
- Problemas tipográficos

Se terminó editando la función a esto:

```
if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
    $nombre_apellido = $_POST['nombre_apellido'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $pepe = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE contactos SET mensaje = '$mensaje' WHERE email = '$email'");
    echo "UPDATE contactos SET mensaje = '$mensaje', WHERE email = '$email'";
    var_dump($pepe);
    //header('Location: editar.php');
    exit;
}
```

El OP entiende los errores y problemas actuales, pero hará las correcciones a futuro.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes errores tipográficos en la consulta

```
mensaje = '$mensaje',
            WHERE mensaje = '$mensaje'
```

Ahí sobra una coma antes del WHERE

E incluso ajustando eso, haces una consulta que no tiene sentido. Digamos que tienes unos registros

| campo1 | campo2 | mensaje |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | pepito |
| b | 2 | juanito |
| c | 3 | monchito |

si haces `UPDATE tabla SET mensaje = 'maria' WHERE mensaje = 'maria'`, no vas a actualizar nada porque no hay ningún registro con ese valor en mensaje. Estás buscando registros en el WHERE que coincidan con LO QUE VAS A PONER.

Es lo que te han intentado explicar en tooooodos los comentarios. La condición del WHERE se usa para buscar entre los datos que ya están. Si hubieras puesto datos de prueba con los que estás ejecutando la consulta, podríamos dar una respuesta más detallada.